# two HTTP request executed with one subscribe - Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, http, subscribe

I have actually this code:

```
ComputerValue: number;
private subscription: ISubscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getMyValue();
  setInterval(() => {
    this.getMyValue();
  }, 30000);
}


getMyValue(): void {
  this.subscription = this.dataService.getValueOfComputer().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.ComputerValue = data;
  });
}
```

When i check my console, i have my result two time because i don't know why my subscribe execute my HTTP query twice.

[image]

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

I was using 2 component (AppComponent, ExampleComponent) where ExampleComponent was the code above.

I added ExampleComponent in my NgModule (declarations and Bootstrap array).

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, ChartsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, ExampleComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, ExampleComponent],
    providers:[DataService]
})
```

When I removed ExampleComponent from Bootstrap Array, my HTTP requests stopped to be duplicated.

If someone have an answer for that do not hesitate

Answer (score 6):

You're using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Your `getMyValue` method will get called every 30 secs.

You're also calling `getMyValue` two times. Once inside the `ngOnInit` and once inside `ngOnInit`'s `setInterval`

Your `getMyValue` gets called once for the first time it is called inside `ngOnInit` and then it will get called after every 30 secs. Change your implementation like this:

```
ComputerValue: number;
private subscription: ISubscription;

ngOnInit() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.getMyValue();
  }, 30000);
}


getMyValue(): void {
  this.subscription = this.dataService.getValueOfComputer().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.ComputerValue = data;
  });
}
```

Not sure why you're doing that though.

## UPDATE

Your scenario looks like a perfect example of Memory Leaks. And this happened to me while I was creating [**this Stackblitz for your reference**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-memory-leak-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Apparently, why you're getting two(or in my case, **MANY**) console logs is because you might have not unsubscribed from the subscription.

I thought of doing that later when I was compiling that StackBlitz. But then I noticed getting multiple logs to the console with different texts as I was still writing the code to be shown on the console.

## FIX

`unsubscribe` from the subscription first. Then reload the page and check if it's working as expected. I did it myself and it started working for me.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**PS:** To replicate your scenario, comment out the `ngOnDestroy` method and then change the contents of the log one by one while saving each change. You'll see multiple logs to the console and this time, NOT EVERY 30 secs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to refresh  my value every 30 sec because my value change.

Comment: There are better ways of doing that. Have you tried using Sockets? It helps you build Real-time Apps and keep your Frontend and Database in sync. Or you could also use Firebase which offers this by default.

Comment: Thanks for your propostion. I just want to know why when I call each 30 sec my function with my subcribe, that do two HTTP request and then two result. Im using badly subscribe ?

Comment: You're actually calling `getMyValue` an extra time on the first line of `ngOnInit`

Comment: If i delete my first line i always have 2 results. I think I have a problem with my subscribe

Comment: Thanks for your help @SiddAjmera . Unfortunaly i added OnDestroy with unsubscribe and i always have my 2 console logs. I tried to use promises and I got the same result...